# Cannot perform std::swap on a vector when compiling with GCC 4.8

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have a piece of code written in C++11 that compiles fine on VS2013 and vs120 toolset on x86. Now, I'm trying to compile the same code for ARMv7 using GCC 4.8 toolset, but I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 
'swap(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Collision*, std::vector<Collision> >, std::vector<Collision>::iterator)
```

Here's the line of code that produces this error:

```
std::swap(m_contacts.begin() + i, m_contacts.end());
```

`m_contacts` is a `std::vector<Collision>` and `i` is an iterator of a for-loop. Is there something I'm missing with GCC or is there a GCC-specific way to do the same thing? Essentially I want to swap the places of the element at `i` and the last element.

Comment: Remember that `.end()` gives you an iterator *past* the last element in the vector, you can't store anything there and you can't read it either, you can only compare it against other iterators.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yeah, I figured out that I've essentially mixed up `.end()` and `.back()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to swap to iterators, but are passing an rvalues as both arguments:

```
m_contacts.begin() + i // an rvalue
m_contacts.end()       // another rvalue
```

This won't compile because an rvalue can't bind to a non-constlvalue reference (VS has an "extension" that allows this, which is why your code might compile on that platform, depending on compiler flags.) It also doesn't make much sense to swap rvalues in general. What you need to do is pass lvalues:

```
auto a = m_contacts.begin() + i;
auto b = m_contacts.end();
std::swap(a, b);
```

Quite why you would want to swap iterators like this isn't clear. If you want to swap an element with the last element in the vector, you can use

```
auto a = m_contacts.begin() + i;
std::swap(*a, m_contacts.back());
```

Comment: It's to remove the element at `i`. I read somewhere that it is a good practice performance-wise to swap the element you want to remove with the element at the end of the vector and then `pop_back()` the last element. EDIT: And now that I googled it, I notice I've mixed up `end()` and `back()`.

Comment: @manabreak The `end()` iterator is the past-the end iterator, not an iterator to the last element. You can't de-reference because it "points" to no object. It seems you want to be swapping elements, not iterators.

Comment: Indeed. I had no intention to operate on iterators, but I've mixed them up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to swap elements, you will have to dereference the iterators (using `*`) or use `std::iter_swap()`. Dereferencing `container.end()` will cause undefined behaviour though, your code is therefore broken. Note than MSVC probably accepted the code because it tends to convert temporaries (returnvalues) to non-const references, which a compliant compiler doesn't.